# Product of two subsets of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider $G$ a finite group, with $|G|=n$. I'm asking myself if, and why, is true that:

if $A$ and $B$ are two subsets (not necessarily subgroups) such that $|A|+|B|> n$ then $AB=G$.

I can't show this, but can't find a counterexample neither.

Comment: What if $A=B$? Then $AB = G$ is not necessary.

Comment: Are you sure? Note that, if $A=B$, $AB$ will not be equal to $A$!

Comment: But it might not equal $G$ also, would it?

Comment: It may be that I'm losing my mind, but I can't see why $AB$ would ever equal $G$. The elements of the direct product are ordered pairs of elements of the original groups. $AB$ looks completely different than $G$.

Comment: @wgrenard it's my mind that is melting: not the direct product. I always make mistakes with english math terms. With $AB$ I mean $AB=\{ab\arrowvert a\in A, b\in B\}$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I'm looking for an example if you think $AB\not=G$. I'm more inclined to think $AB=G$

Comment: But then with your definition, and if $A$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $A^2= A \neq G$. Is that right?

Comment: A is NOT a subgroup! Just a subset, that's the point

Comment: @Roger You should specify that $A$ cannot be a subgroup in the question. As your question stands $A$ can, a priori, be any subset, including those subsets which are subgroups. However, with your new edit not allowing $|A| + |B| = n$ this counterexample won't actually work anyway because if $A$ is a subgroup then $|A|$ must divide $|G|$, so there is no subgroup $A$ such that $|A| + |A| > |G|$.

Comment: yes that's why I did not specify that A is not a subgroup. I made a mistake copying the question with $\geq$ instead of >

Comment: Folks, if $A$ is a (proper) subgroup, then its order is at most $n/2$, which means we can't have $|A|+|A|>n$, so the problem of $AA\ne G$ doesn't arise. (Oops, I didn't see that the original question had $|A|+|B|\ge n$, before it got edited to $|A|+|B|>n$. Sorry!)

Comment: This may be hard. There's a paper by Jeffrey Paul Wheeler, The Cauchy-Davenport Theorem for finite groups, available at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1816.pdf which looks at this question, but I think it only proves a weaker result. It may give you an idea of where to find a counterexample (if there is one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thm. If $G$ is a finite group, $A, B\subseteq G$, and
$|A|+|B| > |G|$, then $AB=G$.

Proof. (Contrapositive)

We assume that $AB\neq G$ and prove that $|A|+|B|\leq |G|$.

Choose a group element $g\notin AB$. Saying that $g\notin AB$ is saying that
$g=ab$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ is impossible.
Hence $a^{-1}g=b$ for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ is impossible.
This shows that the set $A^{-1}g:=\{a^{-1}g\;|\;a\in A\}$
is a subset of $G$ that is disjoint from $B$.
Hence $|G|\geq |A^{-1}g|+|B|=|A|+|B|$. $\Box$